# Is being paralyzed a visible condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions

If one of my party members is paralyzed, is there a visual change that would let me know that?

> **Paralyzed**
>
> - A paralyzed creature is incapacitated (see the condition) and can't
>     move or speak.
>
>   - The creature automatically fails Strength and Dexterity saving throws.
>   - Attack rolls against the creature have
>       advantage
>   - Any attack that hits the creature is a critical hit if the
>       attacker is within 5 feet of the creature.
>
> **Incapacitated**
>
> - An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.

Nowhere does it mention that it isn't visible but it never mentions it is either. If I am a character is some way to get rid of the paralyze, do I know the paralyze is there?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on what you mean. If during combat, I think there would be a noticable lack of action. You would know *something* is wrong.

To confirm its paralysis, a medicine check seems appropriate, though I can't find published material stating a DC.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!